# How is the activation function calculated for each neuron in offline backpropagation?

Tags: neural-network, backpropagation

In offline backpropagation, the error is accumulated as every training example is computed and the delta in the backpropagation rule (the weight modifier) is computed for all the training examples. However the rule is in fact the learning rate multiplied by this delta and the output of the activation function f of the neuron in the previous layer. For example, for the weight between neuron I and neuron J, f would indeed be the activation function of I.

What I don't get is how the argument of f is taken in this case since we are considering more than one input example. Is it instead taken as a sum of activation functions for each input pattern?

Comment: No, you are on the wrong track. You could actually just calculate the delta as you would in a "normal" online backpropagation, and then after you've run all the training instances you would average out the deltas. Note: a much more efficient calculation can easily be implemented using matrix operations.